# CentOS randomly restarts

Tags: centos, xen, centos5

My CentOS 5.7 server randomly restarts. I've found the following in /var/log/messages:

```
Jan 24 01:54:53 m38501 dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 80.xxx.xxx.xxx via eth0
Jan 24 01:54:53 m38501 dhcpd: DHCPACK to 80.xxx.xxx.xxx (00:13:3e:4c:56:87) via eth0
Jan 24 01:54:53 m38501 kernel: r8169: peth0: link up
Jan 24 01:55:24 m38501 last message repeated 53 times
Jan 24 01:56:59 m38501 syslogd 1.4.1: restart.
```

And then it just reboots the server. It's running Xen (2.6.18-274.12.1.el5xen). Anyone knows what can cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your hardware; random restarts could be cause by motherboard (there can be destended capacitor), RAM modules (often it cause a kernel panic) or by power supply.

Comment: Thanks, I have informed my hosting provider and they agree it could be a hardware failure. They will put my drives into another server tomorrow. Let's see if that solves the problem.

Comment: It did solve the problem. It was a hardware failure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's time to upgrade to something new. 2.6.18 is *very* old. Why don't you upgrade to Xen 4.x, and the Debian backported kernel 3.1?

Comment: It's a kernel from 2010. I won't call it very old. Xen 3.4.3 is also a very stable release.

Comment: kernel 2.6.18 is stable kernel from RHEL, it shoudln't be a problem